# Topic Modeling tool for large data set (30GB)

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I'm looking for some topic modeling tool which can be applicable to a large data set.

My current data set for training is 30 GB. I tried [MALLET topic modeling](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php), but always I got OutOfMemoryError.

If you have any tips, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options available to you, and this response is agnostic as to how they compare.

I think that the important thing with such a large dataset is the method of approximate posterior inference used, and not necessarily the software implementation.  According to [this paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/HoffmanBleiBach2010b.pdf), online Variational Bayes inference is much more efficient, in terms of time and space, than Gibbs sampling. Though I've never used it, the [gensim](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim) package looks good. It's in python, and there are in-depth tutorials at the project's [webpage](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/).

For code that comes straight from the source, see the webpage of David Blei, one of the authors of the [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) model, [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html). He links to more than a few implementations, in a variety of languages (R, Java, C++).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a "big data" tool such as graphlab, which supports topic modeling: http://docs.graphlab.org/topic_modeling.html

Answer (score 1):

The GraphLab Create [topic model toolkit](http://graphlab.com/products/create/docs/graphlab.toolkits.text.html) (with Python API bindings) should be able to handle a dataset that large.